# Convert React class components to function components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

I have an abstract class:

```
export default abstract class TableAction<T = any, R = any> extends React.Component<T, R> {
    protected abstract onClick(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void | Promise<void>;
    protected abstract onMouseEnter(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void | Promise<void>;
    protected abstract onMouseLeave(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void | Promise<void>;

    protected abstract renderContent(): React.ReactElement;

    public render = (): React.ReactElement => {
        return (
            <div onClick={() => this.onClick} onMouseEnter={() => this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={() => this.onMouseLeave}>
                {this.renderContent()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

An implementation:

```
export default class SendToMailTableAction extends TableAction<ISendToMailTableActionProps, ISendToMailTableActionState> {
    protected onClick = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): Promise<void> => {
    }

    protected onMouseEnter = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    }

    protected onMouseLeave = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>): void => {
    }

    protected renderContent = (): React.ReactElement => {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.onClick}>
                Send files to mail
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

And a "manager" that recieves `React.ReactElement<TableActions>[]` (the abstract class as an array of elements) as a prop:

```
ITableActionsProps {
    TableActions: React.ReactElement<TableAction>[];
}

export default class TableActions extends React.Component<ITableActionsProps, ITableActionsState> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I need to convert all of these classes to be a function components (hooks).

So I must have the `SendToMailTableAction` be a `TableAction` type.

I can't have a function component be a type other than a function, so what would be an acceptable approach for this?

I might be missing something as I'm new to React and React hooks specifically.

Comment: It's good that you're starting from scratch. The React paradigm leans heavily towards composition not hierarchical component inheritance. See https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance

You also don't have any state or visible side effects apart from some empty promise returns. Convert to function components and then find the abstraction for a hook if it's even feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code helps.

```
// TableAction.tsx
interface iTableAction {
  onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  onMouseEnter?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  onMouseLeave?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
  renderContent?: () => JSX.Element;
}

const TableAction = (props: ITableAction): React.ReactElement<ITableAction> => {
  onClick,
  onMouseEnter,
  onMouseLeave,
  renderContent,
}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
      {renderContent()}
    </button>
  );
};
```

```
// SendToMailTableAction.tsx
import { TableAction } from 'components';

...

const SendToMailTableAction = (props: ISendToMailTableActionProps): React.ReactElement<ITableAction> => {
  const onClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // Do something...
  };
  const onMouseEnter = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // Do something...
  };
  const onMouseLeave = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // Do something...
  };
  const renderContent = () => {
    return <div>{/* Render something... */}</div>;
  };

  return (
    <TableAction
      onClick={onClick}
      onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      renderContent={renderContent}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited your post to use React.ReactElement<type> instead of React.FC as it's an anti-pattern https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177